# Integrating Autofac and MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, autofac, mongodb-.net-driver

.NET 4.0 latest autofac version and latest C# driver

We are in the process of integrating the Autofac DI container into our MongoDB app and things have been going swimmingly with one exception which may be a BUD (Bad User on Device) on my part.  Since my Google Fu has failed me, I thought I would avail myself of your wisdom.

The issue is that we want to support interface based polymorphism and keep all interaction outside of the data layer unaware of any the concreate entity types. A simplified example follows.

```
///Datastore wrapper
public interfaces IDataStore
{
    T Get<T>(string key);
    IQueryable<T> GetCollection(string key)        
}

public interface ITransaction
{
    public string key {get;}
    public double value {get;}
}

public interface IStockTransaction: ITransaction
{
    public string Symbol{get;}
}

public class StockTransaction: IStockTransaction
{
    public string key {get;}
    public double value {get;}
    public double price {get;}
}

//The goal is to get this test to pass. 
[TestMethod()]
public void PolyMorphicTest()
{
    //Wrapper around on Autofac.
    var container = new ContainerConfiguration();
    var target= container.Resolve<IDataStore>();
    //Assume a stock transaction with a key named foo has been saved. 
    var type = target.Get<IStockTransaction>("foo");
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(type,typeof(StockSymbol));
}
```

I have tried various types of Autofac Registration approaches but they all seem to blow up due to the fact that I am completely out of the activation chain for Mongo types (calls like MongoDatabase.GetCollection() for example). Is there a way to use Autofac to get control of the activation chain for Mongo types? For our approach to work, like we want, I need to find a way to use Autofac to replace the type parameter T that is passed in by the upper layer code to the resolved type.  Then we should be able to rely on variance to return it back as the passed in type.

```
T Get<T>(string key) //T Arrives as IStockTransaction 
{
    var coll = Database.GetCollection<T>(T.FullName).AsQueryAble<T>();
    /*T is now the concrete type StockTransaction so that Mongo can query properly.*/

    /* perform a linq query here against the IQueryable. */ 

    return  (T) ((from tmp in coll 
        where tmp.key == " ").FirstOrDefault());  
}

IQueryable<T> GetCollection<T>(string key) //T Arrives as IStockTransaction 
{        
    /*Attempting to Find the Mongo collection using the interface type will lead to Mongo
    serialization errors so we need to change the interface type to the concrete type that we 
    have registered in Autofac or have stashed off manually somewhere before this call. Ideally 
    this would be done with a simple resolve call against Autofac so that if our concrete types 
    change, all of this would still work. */

    var coll = Database.GetCollection<T>(T.FullName).AsQueryAble<T>(); 

    /*Here we would rely on C# 4.0 variance to allow us to cast back to the interface type.*/

    return  (T) coll.FirstOrDefault();  
}
```

Sorry for the long post - would appreciate any ideas. Happy to clarify if the question is unclear. Right now I am leaning towards hacking the MongoDriver so that Autofac is integral to type resolution.  Our other option is waiting until the driver has better support for interfaces and DI (which I hear is coming).  Thanks for your help.